# akka: querying the children of the guardian actor

Tags: scala, akka

In an actor system hierarchy, the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html#The_Top-Level_Supervisors) states that there is a guardian actor with address `/user`, and that actors created using `system.actorOf()` are children of this actor.

*Is it possible to query an actor system to get the 'current' children of the guardian actor? And if so, how is this achieved?*

Comment: What workflow is leading you to this?

Comment: I am extending [this](https://github.com/jrudolph/akka-http-scala-js-websocket-chat) by allowing a client to create a chat room. It is useful (but not essential) to know the children of the guardian actor so that I can test that the respective chat room has been created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a wildcard actor selection and the special `Identify` message to all actors that match that selection. To find the *direct* children of actor `/user` do:

```
system.actorSelection("/user/*") ! Identify(None)
```

If you want to find *all* children in the hierarchy, you would have to manually descend the tree by creating a child wildcard `actorSelection` for each `ActorRef` receive.

The caveat with all this is, that this identification is asynchronous and you have no way of knowing when all children have identified themselves. The best you can do is to set a time limit after which you assume all children have reported back to you.